# Mysql syntax error on update

Tags: php, mysql

I have been staring at this query for ages trying to figure out why I am getting the error as stated in the title and for the life of me cannot see hot to correct it. All fields are correct and all POST values are being posted correctly. I would be grateful if someone with fresh eyes could point out the error. Many thanks.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$rack = strtoupper($_POST['slot']);
$column = $_POST['column']; <---INT
$row = $_POST['row']; <---INT
$bay = $_POST['bay']; <---INT
$size = $_POST['size'];
$service = ucfirst($_POST['service']);
$activity = ucwords($_POST['activity']);
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$address = ucwords($_POST['address']);
$user = ucwords($_POST['user']);
$box = $_POST['item
```

'];

```
$query = "UPDATE `boxes` SET `rack` = '".$rack."',`column` = $column,`row` = $row,`bay` = $bay,`status` = '1',`customer` = '".$company."', `department` = '".$dept."',`request` = 0,`custref` = '".$box."',`size` = '".$size."',`authorisation` = '".$user."' WHERE `department` = '".$dept."',`customer` = '".$company."',`custref` = '".$box."'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error, box action failed'. mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Can you please add the syntax error to the question?

Comment: Also, [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would like to have a word with you

Comment: check the where clause, you have error in your where clause.

Comment: Stare a little more at your `where` clause

Comment: @kerbholz I'm staring but still cannot see it? could you point it out. thanks

Comment: @user1532468 `AND`, not `,`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Here is the error msg. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`customer` = 'DEMO',`custref` = 'DEMOBOX002'' at line 1` Thanks

Comment: Kindly echo the query and paste in in question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AND` instead of `,` in `WHERE`

Change

```
WHERE `department` = '".$dept."',`customer` = '".$company."',`custref` = '".$box."'";
```

to

```
WHERE `department` = '".$dept."' AND `customer` = '".$company."' AND `custref` = '".$box."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your where it's not , it's and between the clauses:

```
$query = "UPDATE `boxes` SET `rack` = '".$rack."',`column` = $column,`row` = $row,`bay` = $bay,`status` = '1',`customer` = '".$company."', `department` = '".$dept."',`request` = 0,`custref` = '".$box."',`size` = '".$size."',`authorisation` = '".$user."' WHERE `department` = '".$dept."' AND `customer` = '".$company."' AND `custref` = '".$box."'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error, box action failed'. mysqli_error($conn));
```